# commerce multicurrency module currency menu selector not switching currency in Shopping cart

Tags: commerce

I am using [commerce_multicurrency](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) module for multi currency support. This module provide two blocks for switching currency of site. One currency menu selector which give enabled currency as links and another block which give enabled currency as select list. I enabled both of the block in header block of site. When i choose any of the currency from these blocks it switch currency of all the products displayed in pages either through views or any other way.

[image]

Selecting currency also switch the currency of the cart page in `<site-url>/cart` but it doesn't switch the currency of shopping cart block placed in header of site. Currency switching in this block is very inconsistent. Sometime it display the selected currency sometime it not. Sometime it show the previous selected currency when i switch any of the currency. This currency switching behavior in shopping cart block works fine when i switch currency on `/cart` page. It switch the currency of the cart at both places

1. Total displayed in cart page with individual product price.
2. Total displayed in header shopping cart block.

[image]

But on other pages of site this shopping cart block on header doesn't work as expected. I searched for this issue but didn't find any. I googled this issue also searched the module issue queue and https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer which finally worked for me.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1853638#comment-9385053